# How to return error message from rest service

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I have defined a rest service with Spring boot which returns an interface. When it occurs an error in the service, how can I return a meaningful error message ? On browser, as a result, I display Json of MyInterface type.

The code below is the service called by the controller:

```
public MyInterface getSomeTask() {

    // business logic here
    MyInterface myObject= getRelatedClass();

    if(myObject == null){
       // how to return error message 
    }

    return myObject;
 }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the possibilities would be to throw Exception and then handle it with Spring so it would return proper json.

You may want to look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) article about error handling.

You coud create custom exception that will be throwed inside your logic and then handle it:

```
if(myObject == null){
   throw new CouldNotGetRelatedClassException(); 
}
```

and in controller you may use error handling method like:

```
public class FooController {

   @ExceptionHandler({ CouldNotGetRelatedClassException.class})
   public void handleException() {
       // logic of exception handling
   }

}
```

Another way may be creating class with `@ControllerAdvice` annotation that will create custom json response on throwed exceptions:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

   @ExceptionHandler(value = {CouldNotGetRelatedClassException.class})
   protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotFound(
     RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
       String bodyOfResponse = "This should be application specific";
       return handleExceptionInternal(ex, bodyOfResponse, 
         new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, request);
   }
}
```

However you may want to be aware that error responses may have different structure that your normal object so you may want to return it with different HTTP status code so frontend could determine that this message will be deserialized differently.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But hadleException method does not return anything, so how browser will show any json on the screen?. Changing return type to MyInterface and creating new implementation for MyInterface to return when there is an exception might be an option. Is it the way how it should be or is it bad practice ?

Comment: @user1474111 I have added more examples